# Custom text instead of page number in the .idx file using \imakeidx

Tags: page-numbering, indexing, imakeidx

I'm using the `\imakeidx` package and I would like to change some index entries adding a custom reference instead of the automatically defined page number.  I'm wondering if is possible to do it inside the .idx file, but replacing the page number with a custom text doesn't seems to work:

```
\indexentry{author!quotation}{my text}
```

Comment: `makeindex` as processor is not really clever to sort such entries. What about issues with `hyperref` ? Where does 'my text' come from?

Comment: How can I do to set the index with Hyperref in that way? I always used imakeidx with a custom .idx file

Comment: You can't easily do this with `makeindex`, by setting a custom text you will screw up hyperlinks, that's the issue with `hyperref`

Comment: Could you please explain how to do it with hyperref or indicate where I can find a specific guide? Thank you

Comment: The main problem is `makeindex` first -- even if you could solve that you will run into troubles with `hyperref`. I am writting this the 3rd. time now!

Comment: usally in the .idx file imakeidx put this type of reference: \indexentry{author!quotation}{123}, and 123 is e.g. the page number where the reference is, automatically assigned. I would like to change it with a custom text, so I manually changed in the .idx file, but it didn't work

Comment: Yes, I know. What is so difficult to understand that `makeindex` can't sort this?

Comment: Yes I know that! I'm wondering if it is possible to manage it in other ways

Comment: I think that glossaries would be better in this respect. As far as I remember, it can also do custom sorting.

Comment: #egreg I checked the glossaries package documentation but I can't figure how to use it to substitute the page numebers of the index with a custom text