# Custom index entries with manually edited references

Tags: itemize, indexing, labels

Referring to my previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353524/custom-text-instead-of-page-number-in-the-idx-file-using-imakeidx), I have managed to obtain custom index entries with manually edited references  by configure a "pseudo-index" using `\label` and `\pageref` for standard cross refencences and formatting the text with `\multicol` and `\itemize` (here is an MWE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, draft]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor\label{tempor} incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud\label{nostrud} exercitation ullamco\label{ullamco} laboris nisi ut aliquip\label{aliquip} ex ea commodo consequat

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}[label={}, leftmargin=*, noitemsep]
\setlength\itemsep{0em}

\item Author 1
\begin{itemize}[label={},noitemsep]
\item consequat \dotfill  34 T 12   % my edited reference text
\item aliquip \dotfill \pageref{aliquip}
\item tempor \dotfill \pageref{tempor}
\item ullamco \dotfill \pageref{ullamco} 
\end{itemize}

\item Author 2
\begin{itemize}[label={},noitemsep]
\item nostrud \dotfill \pageref{nostrud} 
\item veniam \dotfill 65 F 12   % my edited reference text
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I would ask if there is a way to obtain the same result in some other way (e.g. specific indexing packages), with nested references and the possibility to edit the index references as in the MWE, which is perfect for my purposes but clearly needs time to be finished.

Comment: You can of course edit the `.ind` file by hand. If you use `imakeidx` it has an option called (IIRC) `noautomatic` which will prevent the index sorting program from being called.  And the command `\index{main entry!subentry}` should nest 'subentry' under 'main entry'. Quite frankly, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with your above approach, but it seems like there is probably a better way.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly as intended! If I had known, I wouldn't have wasted time with my custom "index".

Comment: @Alessio: There is a manual for `imakeidx` where such 'hidden' features are documented ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was solved in comment